# Firebase Cloud Functions Express app return statement

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently building a Firebase Cloud function which uses the Spotify API.

Now I know this code works since I've also used it before I created an Express app off of this.

But since then I cannot seem to get my cloud function to return anything...

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong.

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("No track specified"));
app.get("/:track", (req, res) => res.send(getTrack(req.params.track)));

function getTrack(track) {
  // Set up Auth options
  console.log(track);

  const spotify_auth_options = {
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "Basic " +
        new Buffer(spotify_client_id + ":" + spotify_client_secret).toString(
          "base64"
        )
    },
    form: {
      grant_type: "client_credentials"
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(spotify_auth_options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log("No error");
      // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
      var token = body.access_token;
      var options = {
        url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + track,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        },
        json: true
      };

      request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body.tracks);
        return body.tracks;
      });
    }
  });
}

exports.searchTrack = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: You're trying to use the `return` keyword deeply nested in two callbacks to return data out of a top level function that is effectively asynchronous.  This is definitely not going to work.  Consider using promises more effectively, or pass the Response object into the function that generates the final response, and invoke it from there.

Comment: Doug, that looks like the solution. Do you mind putting it as an answer so others can upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Doug in the comments section of this question, it seems your return statement is not in the appropriate section. It’s nested deep inside two callbacks which returns data of the top level function. If you would like this code to work and return the variables you are asking it to, please consider moving this return statement into the function that is generating the final response in your code.